# How do I process a 2-D array, one per file, using Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to read and process a file as a single unit, not line by line, and it's not clear how you'd do this in a Hadoop MapReduce application.  What I need to do is to read the first line of the file as a header, which I can use as my key, and the following lines as data to build a 2-D data array, which I can use as my value.  I'll then do some analysis on the entire 2-D array of data (i.e. the value).

Below is how I'm planning to tackle this problem, and I would very much appreciate comments if this doesn't look reasonable or if there's a better way to go about this (this is my first serious MapReduce application so I'm probably making rookie mistakes):

1. My text file inputs contain one line with station information (name, lat/lon, ID, etc.) and then one or more lines containing a year value (i.e. 1956) plus 12 monthly values (i.e. 0.3 2.8 4.7 ...) separated by spaces.  I have to do my processing over the entire array of monthly values [number_of_years][12] so each individual line is meaningless in isolation.
2. Create a custom key class, making it implement WritableComparable.  This will hold the header information from the initial line of the input text files.
3. Create a custom input format class in which a) the isSplitable() method returns false, and b) the getRecordReader() method returns a custom record reader that knows how to read a file split and turn it into my custom key and value classes.
4. Create a mapper class which does the analysis on the input value (the 2-D array of monthly values) and outputs the original key (the station header info) and an output value (a 2-D array of analysis values).  There'll only be a wrapper reducer class since there's no real reduction to be done.

It's not clear that this is a good/correct application of the map reduce approach a) since I'm doing analysis on a single value (the data array) mapped to a single key, and b) since there is never more than a single value (data array) per key then no real reduction will ever need to be performed.  Another issue is that the files I'm processing are relatively small, much less than the default 64MB split size.  With this being the case perhaps the first task is instead to consolidate the input files into a sequence file, as shown in the SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter example in the Definitive Hadoop O'Reilly book (p. 194 in the 2nd Edition)?

Thanks in advance for your comments and/or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your plan regarding coding is spot on, I would do the same thing. 
You will benefit from hadoop if you have a lot of input files provided as input to the Job, as each file will have its own InputSplit and in Hadoop number of executed mappers is the same as number of input splits. 
Too many small files will cause too much memory use on the HDFS Namenode. To consolidate the files you can use SequenceFiles or Hadoop Archives (hadoop equivalent of tar) [See docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.22.0/hadoop_archives.html). With har files (Hadoop Archives) each small file will have its own Mapper.